# How do I build a Virtual Reality videoplayer without Unity?

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I want to build a Virtual Reality video player without using Unity. Is there a way to use the mediaplayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need this:

https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliVR

It works well with media player and local files, but if you want to stream video, media player is not a reliable option.

here is my example:

PlayerActivity

```
public class PlayerActivity extends RajawaliVRActivity {
private RajawaliVRExampleRenderer mRenderer;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    mRenderer = new RajawaliVRExampleRenderer(PlayerActivity.this);
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    setConvertTapIntoTrigger(true);

}

/**
 * Called when the Cardboard trigger is pulled.
 */
@Override
public void onCardboardTrigger() {
    RajLog.i("onCardboardTrigger");
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

And you need a renderer class (I'm sure you can modify MediaPlayer to suit your needs)

```
 public class RajawaliVRExampleRenderer extends RajawaliVRRenderer {
//"https://ia700401.us.archive.org/19/items/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4"
Context mContext;

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private StreamingTexture mVideoTexture;
AppController appController;
boolean playing=false;
public RajawaliVRExampleRenderer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void initScene() {

    appController=(AppController)getContext().getApplicationContext();
    //mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.video1);
    mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("*URL*");

        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mVideoTexture = new StreamingTexture("sintelTrailer", mMediaPlayer);
    Material material = new Material();
    material.setColorInfluence(0);
    try {
        material.addTexture(mVideoTexture);
    } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50, 64, 32);
    sphere.setScaleX(-1);
    sphere.setMaterial(material);

    getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere);

    getCurrentCamera().setPosition(Vector3.ZERO);

    getCurrentCamera().setFieldOfView(75);

    mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            Log.v("grebuf", "buffer (%):" + percent);
            if (percent >= 20) {
                if (!playing) {
                    //mMediaPlayer.start();
                    playing = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.v("grega", "media start");
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.d("grebuf",what+" "+extra);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onRender(long ellapsedRealtime, double deltaTime) {
    super.onRender(ellapsedRealtime, deltaTime);
    mVideoTexture.update();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        mMediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public void onRenderSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    super.onRenderSurfaceDestroyed(surfaceTexture);
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    mMediaPlayer.release();
}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would be a better option for streaming content? I read that the mediaplayer can handle rtsp streams...

Comment: For streaming content, you might want to check ExoPlayer. It just provides video play back though, you'd need to implement the VR rendering part on top.

Answer (score 0):

For a web-based solution, you could also take a look at React360 (https://facebook.github.io/react-360/), it is a WebVR based framework from Facebook and can handle most 3D media out of the box. 
It performs quite well on android and has the advantage of progressive enhancement, i.e. if you view it from a desktop/tablet you get a 2D experience, if you are on a 3D capable device you get a full VR experience. It's also cross platform so will run on android/iOS/Windows/MacOS/Oculus/Vive.
Samples are included with it which should be enough to get you started.